# Android service shutting down by system?

Tags: android

I made a simple android service with an infinite loop in a thread that posts a string log and a counter.

How ever, from time to time the thread I created stops (specially if I run other applications on the device) and gets restarted randomly after. Of course, I lose the state of the service (i.e the counter resets).

Is that an expected Android behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

```
public class WebService extends Service {
Thread svc_thread;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(svc_thread == null) {
        svc_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while(true) {
                    Log.v("WebService", "Doing loop in service "+i);
                    i++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("WebService", "Error ocurred in service thread!" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        svc_thread.setName("Service Thread");
        svc_thread.start();
    }


    return START_STICKY;

};
```

Comment: Android system will do necessary steeps to run applications in the OS. Allocating recourse for foreground apps may be effect to the one in background.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that an expected Android behavior

Yes. Processes do not live forever. You may wish to read the documentation about [processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).